# How to print number of stars corresponding to some numbers vertically?

Tags: java, arrays, histogram

i am trying to make a histogram to be displayed vertically , my output gives incorrect pattern.

input :

```
unqNums = [0.0, 2.0, 1.0, 5.0]
repeated = [2, 2, 1, 1]
```

output:

```
*    *
*    *    *    *
0.0, 2.0, 1.0, 5.0
```

my code:

```
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(gradesNoRepead));
 //[0.0, 2.0, 1.0, 5.0]
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(repeatedVal));
 //[2, 2, 1, 1]
//getting the max rep
        int mxRep = Main.getMax(repeatedVal);
        for(int i = mxRep; i > 0; --i){
            for(int l=0; l<gradesNoRepead.length; ++l){
        
                System.out.print((gradesNoRepead[l] >= i) ? " * " : "  ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        for (int m = 0; m < gradesNoRepead.length; m++) {
            System.out.print(" " + gradesNoRepead[m] + " ");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that in your loop where you are outputting the `*` values, you are iterating over and testing the values in the wrong array (`gradesNoRepead`), you should be using `repeatedVal`:

```
for(int l=0; l<repeatedVal.length; ++l){
    System.out.print((repeatedVal[l] >= i) ? "  *  " : "     ");
}
```

Note that you also need some more spaces in the output strings to make them match properly with the width of the `gradesNoRepead` values.